# Google App Engine Datastore Viewer How to Create Entity and Set String @Id (key) Field

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a data model class where the String field "customerUniqueId" is tagged using Objectify annotation **@Id**.  Therefore I am using a string key field (not auto-number long) that I set in code when creating a new object to put to the data store.

```
@Id private String customerUniqueId;
```

While using the Datastore Viewer to view these objects, I can click the **Create** tab to create a new object.  However the "customerUniqueId" field is not offered as an input field.  I am only shown the fields tagged as **@Indexed** in my data model.

Is this expected behavior or should I be able to input a value for the @Id field in the Datastore Viewer Create feature?

Am I using @Id incorrectly and must I name the field as "id" or "name"?

Perhaps if I tag the @Id field as also @Indexed but that should be unnecessary right?  @Id fields should always be indexed be definition.

Perhaps it has something to do with the "Namespace" textboxes in the Create form that I left blank?

Anyone have this issue and know of a solution?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The @Id field does not exist as a property in the datastore.  It is part of the entity's *key*.  I don't think the datastore viewer lets you create an entity with a String key; it always uses the autogenerated number.  Perhaps file an issue with Google against the datastore viewer?

Comment: Yes I guess the limitations of the Datastore Viewer mean I can also manually create entities with an autogen number.  The purpose of my question is to make sure it is not something I did wrong when defining my entity classes and annotating them for Objectify.  


I'm hoping Google will release a fully featured database manager so we can insert and update entities more like a sql database.


Without this capability I have to build a UI page for every type of entity that uses a String @id field that I want to add on the backend. Any other ideas?